# Are unlocked basic cards automatically added to class' default deck?

Tags: hearthstone

Every class starts with 10 cards. As I unlock more are the new cards added to default decks or do I have to create a custom deck to use unlocked basic cards?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic deck will always be the same, unless you change it with unlocked basic cards, or cards from expansions and adventures.

Alternatively you can craft a deck from scratch with whichever cards you like from your current collection, this is done in the My Collection section.